# Optional TextFormField in Form

Tags: flutter, textformfield

I have 1 Form with 2 TextFormField, firstName and lastName.
I need to validate this two data with condition and regex, then pass data to the second page with Navigator.

Problem is, i want lastName is optional or can be empty.
But i can't remove validator because i still need to use it with regex or others.

```
TextEditingController firstName = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController lastName = TextEditingController();

GlobalKey<FormState> _key = GlobalKey();
bool _validate = false;
String first, last;

Form(
  key: _key,
  autovalidate: _validate,
  child: Column(children: [
    InputName(
      controller: firstName,
      placeholder: 'Nama depan',
      validator: validateFirstName,
      onSaved: (String val) {
        first = val;
      },
    ),
    InputName(
      controller: lastName,
      placeholder: 'Nama belakang',
      validator: validateLastName,
      onSaved: (String val) {
        last = val;
      },
    ),
  ]),
),

Button(
  text: 'Lanjut mengisi Email',
  onPressed: () {
    if (_key.currentState.validate()) {
      _key.currentState.save();
      
      String a = firstName.text.capitalize();
      String b = lastName.text.capitalize();
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        PageRouteBuilder(
          pageBuilder: (context, animation1, animation2) =>
              Regist2Page([a, b]),
          transitionDuration: Duration(seconds: 0),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _validate = true;
      });
    }
  },
),

String validateLastName(String value) {
  if (value.isNotEmpty) {
    if (value.length > 20) {
      return 'Maksimal 20 karakter';
    }
    return null;
  }
  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this validator

```
String validateLastName(String value) {
if (value == "") {
  // if value were null, is true and then return null
  return null;
}

if (value.length > 20) {
  return 'Maksimal 20 karakter';
}

return null;
}
```

Comment: I got this error
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0

Comment: Because you sent array without a value do this then: Regist2Page([a, b ?? ""])

Comment: well I suggest sent firstname and lastname separately instead of sending array because that cause the trouble. Is the validator working though?

Comment: Answer is capitalize() cant find string because empty so must be in condition first, if not empty then capitalize(). validator is working too, id use it, thaks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
String validateLastName(String value,{bool isOptional = false})) {
  if(isOptional && (value==null || value.isEmpty)){
    return null;
  }
  if (value.isNotEmpty) {
    if (value.length > 20) {
      return 'Maksimal 20 karakter';
    }
    return null;
  }
  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by Agus Setya R.

```
String b = lastName.text == '' ? '' : lastName.text.capitalize();
```